# Scala: adding value from spark DataFrame to mutable list in a for loop

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to update the elements of a MutableList that was declared outside of a for loop with values from a dataframe. I initialized the list as empty and expect the list to have the n number of elements added when the loop terminates. However, it seems only one element is back to an empty list (never gets updated with new additions) and when the loop terminates, the list is back to empty.

This only happens if I am iterating over a dataFrame, if I iterate over a fied range, say 1-10, the results returned are as expected.

Iterating through dataframe:

```
val my_list = MutableList[String]()

scala> for (i <-df){
     | my_list += "ok"
     | println(my_list)
     | }
MutableList(ok)
MutableList(ok)

scala> valid_list
res120: scala.collection.mutable.MutableList[String] = MutableList()
```

Iterating through fixed range

```
scala> for (i <- 1 to 10) {
     | my_list += "ok"
     | println (my_list)
     | }
MutableList(ok)
MutableList(ok, ok)
MutableList(ok, ok, ok)
MutableList(ok, ok, ok, ok)
MutableList(ok, ok, ok, ok, ok)
MutableList(ok, ok, ok, ok, ok, ok)
MutableList(ok, ok, ok, ok, ok, ok, ok)
MutableList(ok, ok, ok, ok, ok, ok, ok, ok)
MutableList(ok, ok, ok, ok, ok, ok, ok, ok, ok)
MutableList(ok, ok, ok, ok, ok, ok, ok, ok, ok, ok)

scala> my_list
res122: scala.collection.mutable.MutableList[String] = MutableList(ok, ok, ok, ok, ok, ok, ok, ok, ok, ok)
```

Also open to alternative methods of generating a list from df elements.

Comment: Graham , is there a specific reason you want to collect the data into a List , is there a specific requirement you are attempting

Comment: I am trying to filter a dataframe by a list using .isin(list:_*)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Can you try like this,

```
for (i <-df.collect){
      my_list += "ok"
      println(my_list)
      }
```

i used scala.collection.mutable.listBuffer and it worked fine.

```
scala> val a = scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[String]()
a: scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[String] = ListBuffer()

scala> for ( i <- df.collect) {a+="ok"; println(a)}
ListBuffer(ok)
ListBuffer(ok, ok)
ListBuffer(ok, ok, ok)
ListBuffer(ok, ok, ok, ok)
ListBuffer(ok, ok, ok, ok, ok)
ListBuffer(ok, ok, ok, ok, ok, ok)
ListBuffer(ok, ok, ok, ok, ok, ok, ok)
ListBuffer(ok, ok, ok, ok, ok, ok, ok, ok)

scala> a
res11: scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[String] = ListBuffer(ok, ok, ok, ok, ok, ok, ok, ok)
```

Please try and let me know the result. Cheers....

Answer (score 1):

I will try to answer here. Is this what you want to achieve

```
val listValueDataFrame = Seq(("one", 2.0),("two", 1.5),("three", 8.0)).toDF("id", "val")
listValueDataFrame.printSchema
val listOfIds = listValueDataFrame.select("id").collect().map(_(0)).toList
val someOtherDataFrame = Seq(("one", 3.0),("ni", 2.5),("san", 9.0)).toDF("id", "val")
someOtherDataFrame.filter(someOtherDataFrame("id").isin(listOfIds:_*)).show
```

on my execution this prints the following

```
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- val: double (nullable = false)

+---+---+
| id|val|
+---+---+
|one|3.0|
+---+---+

listValueDataFrame: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: string, val: double]
listOfIds: List[Any] = List(one, two, three)
someOtherDataFrame: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: string, val: double]
```

Does this help at all , was not 100% sure i understood the complete context of the question , but this can be achieved this way. Note that i have used collect and with large number of records this will cause bad performance (data will have to be "collected" and moved to the driver)

Comment: The issue is that I want to update the list inside a loop going through a dataframe. I don't know what should be collected until I process the data inside the dataframe one by one. Inside the loop the list is updated, but outside the list is reset to what it was initalized as.